# nginx 'interfering' with cache response?

Tags: spring, tomcat, nginx, spring-security, browser-cache

I have a Spring Web MVC app running in Tomcat 7 with nginx 1.1.19 in front of the Tomcat.

I've enabled `Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, must-revalidate` with Spring Security and the headers are good returning to the browser.

If I run the app directly to Tomcat everything works as expected, static resources all return with 304.

Running through nginx some static resources return 304 and some return 200, *all* show properly formatted `Cache-Control` headers. I can't find any pattern in what is and isn't cached.

The nginx confix is pretty simple:

```
location /TSAdmin {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8030;
         proxy_redirect http://localhost:8030 https://10.10.5.63;
 }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the full responses (including headers) for resources which are cached (e.g. have 304 response code), and resources which are not (e.g. have 200 response code)?

Comment: Sorry, I should have closed this. This turned-out to be a Spring header configuration issue. I can share my Spring Security config if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned-out to be a Spring Security config problem, these two snippets resolved the issue:

```
   <http>
      <headers>
         <cache-control disabled="true" />
      </headers>
      <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/frameworks/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/img/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/fonts/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
   </http>
```

and

```
   <mvc:resources location="/, /css/" mapping="/css/**" cache-period="31536000" />
   <mvc:resources location="/, /frameworks/" mapping="/frameworks/**" cache-period="31536000" />
   <mvc:resources location="/, /img/" mapping="/img/**" cache-period="31536000" />
   <mvc:resources location="/, /js/" mapping="/js/**" cache-period="31536000" />
   <mvc:resources location="/, /fonts/" mapping="/fonts/**" cache-period="31536000" />
   <mvc:resources location="/, /images/" mapping="/images/**" cache-period="31536000" />
```

Fixed things for us.